# Chrome keeps opening the pdf file in a new tab

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to download a file directly from a link but Chrome keeps opening the pdf file in a new tab.
Here is the code I gathered from all issues I found :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe");

String downloadFilepath = "C:\\Users\\i016800\\Downloads";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", "true");
chromePrefs.put("download.extensions_to_open", "");
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromePrefs.put("pdfjs.disabled", true);
chromePrefs.put("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
chromePrefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[]{   // disable flash and the PDF viewer
    "Adobe Flash Player", "Chrome PDF Viewer"});

//Save Chrome Options
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> plugin = new HashMap<String, Object>();
plugin.put("enabled", true);
plugin.put("name", "Chrome PDF Viewer");
chromePrefs.put("plugins.plugins_list", Arrays.asList(plugin));
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--always-authorize-plugins=true");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // Open Chrome in Full Screen

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
cap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
cap.setCapability("prefs.download.directory_upgrade", true);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

String adresseJarvis = "http://intranet.renault.com/declic-com/post/116235/2017/06/renault-assemblee-generale-2017/";
driver.get(adresseJarvis);  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li/a")).click();
```

I know some options are correctly loaded because when I activate options.addArguments("start-maximized"), Chrome begins in Full Screen.

I also tried to change chrome settings manualy before execution but it doesn't work neither.

My config :
Chrome Driver 2.29
Java 1.7.0-60-b19
Eclipse Indigo build 20120216-1857
Os Windows 7 Entreprise
Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
Selenium 2.47

Comment: I think that might be the default behaviour if we download the pdf from that particular site...

Comment: @ylevoy I will suggest you to follow a principle `KISS (Keep It Short & Simple)`. We will configure only the mandatory `chromePrefs`, `plugin`, `ChromeOptions` and `DesiredCapabilities` to achieve whatever is required. Can you narrow down to your exact requirement as you would like to do/see it manually? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
In fact I tried many many combinations of options and preferences, quite one by one. I even began without any of these; only the System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"; I also tried other preferences this morning like
- chromePrefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", "Adobe Flash Player");
- same wih "Chrome PDF Viewer"
I really don't understand. 
I setup Chrome so that it downloads pdf when I click a pdf link but setpup is done for chrome.exe, not for chromedriver.exe . So it works when I open Chrome manually but it doesn't work whith Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine finnaly managed to solve my problem. 
Here is the code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String adresseJarvis = "http://intranet.renault.com/declic-com/post/116235/2017/06/renault-assemblee-generale-2017/";
driver.get(adresseJarvis);
WebElement printLink=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li/a")).get(0);
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1],arguments[2])",printLink,"download","");
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1],arguments[2])",printLink,"target","_blank");   
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li/a")).click();
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Worked for me. Probably the simplest solution. And it avoids everchanging chromedriver parameter complexity. On the other hand, manipulating the document to be tested is also not something that we want to do often.